# Can I multiply 3D cards in a Nuke 3d scene on top of each other, like i can multiply layers in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, composing, nuke

I have a 3D Scene in Nuke with several cards behind each other in 3d space. Is there a way to multiply them on top of each other? Like with layer blending modes in After Effects but still keeping it a NUKE 3D scene?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without doing a 2D merge on two rendered elements

Comment: Figured out a solution. See answer on the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use  blending modes in a 3D scene. What can be done though, is to use several scenes or 3D objects with a scan line renderer and a cam. Each of those are merged with the blending mode of choice after the scan line renderer in 2d.

Comment: Yup that will work. But fair warning it can get slow really quickly if you have to do this a lot.